# How to read a list which is in list format in a text file in Python

Tags: python, list, input, evaluate

I have this list in a txt file:

```
[1, "hello", {"Name": "Tom"}, [2, 3, "hello_hello"], (800, 600)]
```

There are an `int`, a `str`, a `dict`, a `list` and a `tuple` (not that it was really the matter).

I'd like to read this like this was a list (as it really is) not like one string.

I'd like to get a result like:

```
elem[0] = 1
elem[1] = "hello"
elem[2] = {"Name": "Tom"}
elem[3] = [2, 3, "hello_hello"]
elem[4] = (800,600)
```

Also it would be really nice if the dictionary evaluated `eval()` immediately, but that's not really the point.

Comment: What is `Tom` in `elem[2]` ? It does not seem like a string

Comment: @AvinashRaj, that won't work with what the OP has provided

Comment: @Kőhalmy Zoltán,  is that exactly how the data looks in your file?

Comment: @AvinashRaj you should answer the question it will work now

Comment: question editetd Tom was not in "" and yes it is a string

Comment: @PadraicCunningham That exact string is working for me in Python 3.4 , what issue do you see?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham why so `str2='[1, "hello", {"Name": "Tom"}, [2, 3, "hello_hello"], (800, 600)]' and ast.literal_eval(str2) ` provided [1, 'hello', {'Name': 'Tom'}, [2, 3, 'hello_hello'], (800, 600)]

Comment: @AnandSKumar, it works since the OP edited, the original input would not have worked

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yes, this is the exacty way, how  my text file looks. I'll Have a program that will work with various data read in from a file as a list which is in list format and is one line and does contain various types of objects

Comment: Cool ast.literal_eval did solve my question, you are stars guys!

Answer (score 4):

As indicated by @AvinashRaj in the comments, you can use the [`ast` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) (ast: Abstract Syntax Trees):

```
import ast

print ast.literal_eval('[1, "hello", {"Name": "Tom"}, [2, 3, "hello_hello"], (800, 600)]')
```

Output:

```
[1, 'hello', {'Name': 'Tom'}, [2, 3, 'hello_hello'], (800, 600)]
```

This should be the exact result (`elem`) you are expecting.

Answer (score -3):

I'd consider it a json.

```
import json
my_list = json.load(my_str_list)
```

Comment: It is not valid  json