# read (or split) the dictionaries that are in a list in a .txt file

Tags: python, dictionary, split

I dont know how to read (or split) each dictionary of the .txt file

I have a database(list) that have dictionaries. Each of this dictionaries have the caracteristics of a person(name, age , etc...) I have the class person and  want to put all this atributes to and objets.

I dont know how to read (or split) each dictionary of the .txt file

this is an example of the database that i have:

```
[ { "idolos": [], "nombre": "Juan Lopez", "clave": "m6j0NI", "ramos_pre": [], "alumno": "NO", "usuario": "jlopez" }, { "idolos": [], "nombre": "Paulina Toro", "clave": "KaEEkNjFz", "ramos_pre": [], "alumno": "NO", "usuario": "ptoro" }]
```

pd: I cant use any library

Comment: Your data seems to be in JSON format. Could you indicate why you can't use any library? (because this would be pretty simple using the `json` module.)

Comment: You can't use _any_ module? What about built-in ones?

Comment: I can use any library because i'm doing a homework and one of the conditions of this was to not use any library

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `eval`:

```
s = '[ { "idolos": [], "nombre": "Juan Lopez", "clave": "m6j0NI", "ramos_pre": [], "alumno": "NO", "usuario": "jlopez" }, { "idolos": [], "nombre": "Paulina Toro", "clave": "KaEEkNjFz", "ramos_pre": [], "alumno": "NO", "usuario": "ptoro" }]'
d = eval(s)
```

Then `d` is a list of dictionaries. You can access each item as usual:

```
print d[0]
```

Output:

```
{'usuario': 'jlopez', 'alumno': 'NO', 'clave': 'm6j0NI', 'idolos': [], 'ramos_pre': [], 'nombre': 'Juan Lopez'}
```

**Edit:** If you can use python standard libraries, look into the [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) module, as I did in [`this answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32114524/3419103).

Comment: Don't  use eval use `ast` module eval method

Comment: @VigneshKalai: Not sure if the OP is allowed to use it.

Comment: @Vignesh - Falko ->Can we  treat this as some complex data structure as "list of dictionaries" and do operation on it ?

Comment: But using  `eval` is [dangerous](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/is-using-eval-in-python-a-bad-practice)

Comment: @DineshPundkar isn't this a `list of dictionaries` could you provide a sample of what you are thinking

Comment: @Vignesh - Answered above. Since , the users can't use any library, so I was thinking about doing some operations with available ones.

Comment: @DineshPundkar can't get you